# ScrollTo not working if scrollview inside relativeLayout

Tags: android

I have `scrollView` inside `relativeLayout` and I want to scroll my view to a certain position. But if I have scroll view inside relative layout or scroll view has `width="match_parent"` then I cant move it (I need rv or `width="match_parent"` to set background `color` on full layout). How to move rl or `scrollView` to a certain position int this case?

```
    <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/scroll_rl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
android:id="@+id/scroll_to_this"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingStart="28dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="28dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <!-- Some content-->
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

My code

```
scroll.scrollTo(0, scroll_to_this.bottom)
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Added some code

Answer (score 0):

you can get y position of your view using `getY()`. use below code to scroll to Y value of your textview.

```
scroll.smoothScrollTo (0, (int) scroll_to_this.getY());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add more code or description with screenshot so we can understand what you exactly want. Apart this from about your code and description if you are trying to scroll your view then it will not work till your scroll view's child view are much more which are not fit to screen's height then you can scroll it. For that you can use that in two way which is as below:

```
scrollView.scrollTo(0, tv.getY());
```

or

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, tv.getY());
```

Here you can use your view bottom position like tv.getBottom() also.